# Sorting by document values in couchbase and scala

Tags: scala, nosql, couchbase

I am using couchbase and I have a document (product) that looks like:

```
{
  "id": "5fe281c3-81b6-4eb5-96a1-331ff3b37c2c",
  "defaultName": "default name",
  "defaultDescription": "default description",
  "references": {
    "configuratorId": "1",
    "seekId": "1",
    "hsId": "1",
    "fpId": "1"
  },
  "tenantProducts": {
    "2": {
      "adminRank": 1,
      "systemRank": 15,
      "categories": [
        "3"
      ]
    }
  },
  "docType": "product"
}
```

I wish to get all products (this json is product) that belong to certain category, So i've created the following view:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if(doc.docType == "product")
  {
  for (var tenant in doc.tenantProducts) {
    var categories = doc.tenantProducts[tenant].categories
    //  emit(categories, doc);

    for(i=0;i<categories.length;i++)
    {
         emit([tenant, categories[i]], doc);
    }   
   }
  }
}
```

So i can run the view with keys like:

```
[["tenantId", "Category1"]] //Can also have: [["tenant1", "Category1"],["tenant1", "Category2"] ]
```

My problem is that i receive the document, but i wish to sort the documents by their admin rank and system rank, these are 2 fields that exists in the "value".

I understand that the only solution would be to add those fields to my key, determine that my key would be from now:

```
 [["tenantId", "Category1", "systemRank", "adminRank"]]
```

And after i get documents, i need to sort by the 3rd and 4th parameters of the key ?

I just want to make sure i understand this right.

Thanks